# Why is the Property SampleRate in the WaveFormat Class in NAudio ReadOnly?

Tags: signal-processing, naudio, sample-rate

I try to change the sampleRate when using signalGenerator in NAudio.  But is readOnly, is there a reason to it?
Can I overwrite it without trouble ?

```
public void MaakGeluid(int sampleRate) {
        waveOut = new WaveOut();
        waveOut.DesiredLatency = 100;
        sg = new SignalGenerator();
        sg.Frequency = Frequency;
        sg.WaveFormat.SampleRate = sampleRate;
        sg.Type = Sgt;
        waveOut.Init(sg);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you must specify the sample rate in the SignalGenerator constructor. An ISampleProvider cannot simply change its sample rate on the fly, because your WaveOut will be expecting data at that sample rate.

You can change the signal generator's frequency while playing though.

Comment: thankx MarK, and btw your courses on [link](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/audio-programming-naudio) is very interesting and clearly explained even for  people like me with few knowledge on  sound.